# including selmer in a compojure-app is causing error while starting server

Tags: clojure, compojure, selmer

I am trying to build a compojure-app and I just included the selmer dependency. I am getting an exception when I try to do a

```
lein ring server-headless
```

I am using [selmer "1.0.7"] as  the dependency in a lein project

this is the exception that I am seeing.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method clojure.lang.RT.classForNameNonLoading(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class; from class selmer.node$fn__58, compiling:(selmer/tags.clj:1:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7142)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:370)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:361)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:440)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:411)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5066.invoke(core.clj:5641)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5640)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5446)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__5015.invoke(core.clj:5486)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5485)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:626)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5524)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:628)
    at clojure.core$use.doInvoke(core.clj:5618)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:482)
    at selmer.validator$eval8785$loading__4958__auto____8786.invoke(validator.clj:1)
    at selmer.validator$eval8785.invoke(validator.clj:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6703)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6692)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7130)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:370)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:361)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:440)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:411)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5066.invoke(core.clj:5641)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5640)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5446)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__5015.invoke(core.clj:5486)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5485)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:626)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5524)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:626)
    at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5607)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:457)
    at selmer.template_parser$eval8715$loading__4958__auto____8716.invoke(template_parser.clj:1)
    at selmer.template_parser$eval8715.invoke(template_parser.clj:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6703)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6692)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7130)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:370)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:361)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:440)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:411)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5066.invoke(core.clj:5641)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5640)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5446)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__5015.invoke(core.clj:5486)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5485)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:626)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5524)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:626)
    at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5607)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:551)
    at selmer.parser$eval8709$loading__4958__auto____8710.invoke(parser.clj:1)
    at selmer.parser$eval8709.invoke(parser.clj:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6703)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6692)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7130)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:370)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:361)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:440)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:411)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5066.invoke(core.clj:5641)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5640)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5446)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__5015.invoke(core.clj:5486)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5485)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:626)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5524)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:626)
    at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5607)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:619)
    at keg_test_utils.routes.home$eval3662$loading__4958__auto____3663.invoke(home.clj:1)
    at keg_test_utils.routes.home$eval3662.invoke(home.clj:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6703)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6692)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7130)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:370)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:361)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:440)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:411)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5066.invoke(core.clj:5641)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5640)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5446)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__5015.invoke(core.clj:5486)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5485)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:626)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5524)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:626)
    at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5607)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:551)
    at keg_test_utils.handler$eval2161$loading__4958__auto____2162.invoke(handler.clj:1)
    at keg_test_utils.handler$eval2161.invoke(handler.clj:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6703)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6692)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7130)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:370)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:361)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:440)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:411)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5066.invoke(core.clj:5641)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5640)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5446)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__5015.invoke(core.clj:5486)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5485)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:626)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5524)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:626)
    at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5607)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:457)
    at user$eval5.invoke(form-init4401683715285844566.clj:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6703)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6692)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7130)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:7086)
    at clojure.main$load_script.invoke(main.clj:274)
    at clojure.main$init_opt.invoke(main.clj:279)
    at clojure.main$initialize.invoke(main.clj:307)
    at clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:342)
    at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:420)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:383)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:156)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:700)
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method clojure.lang.RT.classForNameNonLoading(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class; from class selmer.node$fn__58
    at selmer.node$fn__58.invoke(node.clj:16)
    at selmer.node__init.load(Unknown Source)
    at selmer.node__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2093)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:430)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:411)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5066.invoke(core.clj:5641)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5640)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5446)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__5015.invoke(core.clj:5486)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5485)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:626)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5524)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:626)
    at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5607)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:482)
    at selmer.tags$eval8791$loading__4958__auto____8792.invoke(tags.clj:1)
    at selmer.tags$eval8791.invoke(tags.clj:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6703)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6692)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7130)
    ... 142 more
Subprocess failed
```

these are my dependencies

```
:dependencies [
                     [org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]
                     [compojure "1.1.6"]
                     [hiccup "1.0.5"]
                     [ring-server "0.3.1"]
                     [clj-http "2.2.0"]
                     [org.clojure/java.jdbc "0.6.1"]
                     [com.oracle/ojdbc6 "11.2.0.4"]
                     [org.clojure/data.json "0.2.6"]
                     [cheshire "5.6.3"]
                     [commons-lang/commons-lang "2.6"]
                     [honeysql "0.7.0"]
                     [selmer "1.0.7"]
                ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of those version are vastly outdated, so I would suggest using the following **project.clj**:

```
(defproject selmering "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
:ring {:handler selmering.core/app}
:plugins [[lein-ring "0.9.7"]]
  :dependencies [
     ; [org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]
                     [org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]
                     [compojure "1.5.1"]
                     [ring/ring-defaults "0.1.5"]

                     [hiccup "1.0.5"]
                     [ring "1.5.0"]
                     [clj-http "2.2.0"]
                     [org.clojure/java.jdbc "0.6.1"]
                     [com.oracle/ojdbc6 "11.2.0.4"]
                     [org.clojure/data.json "0.2.6"]
                     [cheshire "5.6.3"]
                     [commons-lang/commons-lang "2.6"]
                     [honeysql "0.7.0"]
                     [selmer "1.0.7"]  
  ])
```

And then with a ring handler:

```
(ns selmering.core
    (:require [selmer.parser :refer :all])
      (:require [compojure.core :refer :all]
            [compojure.route :as route]
            [ring.middleware.defaults :refer [wrap-defaults site-defaults]]))

(defroutes app-routes
  (GET "/" [] (render-file "index.html" {:name "Nico"}))
  (route/not-found "Not Found"))

(def app
  (wrap-defaults app-routes site-defaults))
```

All should be fine.